# Unable to set response header as location with http status 302 after writing an image

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a requirement to write an image and simultaneously setting the header as Location with status code 302.

```
    //Code Snippet
    InputStream input = request.getServletContext()
                .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/a.gif");
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(input);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();      
    ImageIO.write(bi, GIF_FORMAT, out);

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    response.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
```

I have tried with above code but all in vain.
As it fails to set the location with Http 302 status.Trying to prevent flushing of response but still the response is getting flush out.
Do anyone came across with this kind of requirement?Kindly help as i am new to Jsp/Servlet.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set headers first before writing to servlet response:

```
//Set headers
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);

//Write response
InputStream input = request.getServletContext()
            .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/a.gif");
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(input);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();      
ImageIO.write(bi, GIF_FORMAT, out);
```

Comment: I have already tried the above suggestion but on doing this my image fails to get write on the stream and response gets flush

Comment: You are doing this a bit wrong. You are sending a redirect to a different site, and expect to show a picture. You should respond with the picture, and then on the browser side set redirection by some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Delay writing to the output stream or park it in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or similar until you know the headers you want to set. You must set the headers before you write content or it will not work.

Comment: I tried to solve problem using ByteArrayOutputStream, but still its not writing the image, instead its now allowing to set header and status as 302. Any other suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: You mean it does not send the image if you set the headers? That is probably ok, as you send a redirect. If you mean it does not send the image if you not sent the headers, did you forward the ByteArrayOutputStream contents to the servlet response stream after you decided whether to set the headers or not?